# HashBytes with datetime2 field

Tags: sql, hash, datetime2, hashbytes

I am creating a hash key using hashbytes on multiple columns to get performance gain which we are using right now in where clause.

```
alter table dbo.Table1 
add HashKey AS CAST(hashbytes('MD5', PID+PNumber+CONVERT([varchar]  (50),[DateStamp]) +CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),    TransactionCount)+OCD+ONbr+TransactionID) AS VARBINARY(80)) PERSISTED
```

But one of the column in that is a datetime2 field which i am unable to add. While i was trying i am getting below error message

"Computed column 'HashKey' in table 'table1' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.".

From my research i found that datetime2 cannot be used as it is non-deterministic.

But i cannot change the format as i need to compare the value exactly as it is including all milliseconds.

Can anybody please give  me a work around?.Any alternate solution will be appreciated.

Comment: I've never heard about a non-determinstic datatype. Seems like what you are doing is pretty much the same as the checkum-function though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx

Comment: If one of the values in the expression list changes, the checksum of the list also generally changes. However, there is a small chance that the checksum will not change. For this reason, we do not recommend using CHECKSUM to detect whether values have changed, unless your application can tolerate occasionally missing a change.   We do not tolerate  this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of implications..

But casting datetime to binary always gives new value.see below for Example..

```
select getdate(),cast(getdate()as  binary)

2016-08-02 10:17:20.573 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A65600A98EEC


2016-08-02 10:17:40.537 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A65600A9A651
```

so try like..

```
select hashbytes('md5',cast(getdate()as  binary))
```

Comment: I did as follow from ur suggesion .                                                                  `alter table dbo.Table1 
add HashKey AS CAST(hashbytes('MD5', PID+PNumber+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cast(datestamp as  binary))+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),    TransactionCount)+OCD+ONbr+TransactionID) AS VARBINARY(80)) PERSISTED`                                                                    Its working now. Thx

Comment: Actually i am facing problem now to get the c# Equivalent value for the hash bytes generated value. As we have converted datestamp to binary and then to varchar. Now i am unable to get the c# equivalent value for the same. Any help would be appreciated.Here i have posted as another question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739141/convert-sql-hash-bytes-binary-value-multiple-datatype-fields-combination-to-c

Comment: The reason casting to `BINARY` worked but `VARCHAR` didn't is because `CAST` from a datetime to a string is _locale_-specific. Hence the non-determinism warning; one can change the locale of Windows or SQL Server at any time. Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),datestamp,126)` to get a standardized ISO-8601 format string, and then do the same on the C# application, and your hashes should match (assuming the other fields are all character strings with the same encoding).